# Forward Declaration: Undefined Class ( C2079 )

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, c2079

I have an error in my code. All the forums says "in this situation, use Forward Declaration". I tried this and it don't work.

the error is **C2079** Credit::mainMenu use a class of MainMenu not declared (translated from french)

I modified the classe to be specific to the question.

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Menu.h"

#include "credit.h"
#include "mainmenu.h"


MainMenu *mainMenu = new MainMenu();//works here

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

**`credit.h`**

```
#ifndef DEF_CREDIT
#define DEF_CREDIT

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Menu.h"
class MainMenu;


class Credit : public Menu
{
private:
    MainMenu mainMenu = MainMenu();//DON'T WORK HERE
};

#endif
```

**`mainmenu.h`**

```
#ifndef DEF_MAINMENU
#define DEF_MAINMENU

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Menu.h"
#include "credit.h"

class MainMenu :public Menu
{
private:
    Credit credit = Credit();//work
};
#endif
```

Fist i load main.cpp
after the `credit.h` (there is a `credit.hpp` but i don't use the variable now)
after the `mainmenu.h` (there is also a `mainmenu.hpp`, i don't use variable now)

tip: the `Menu` class isn't including any of those class

I can send you the complete code if you want

Thanks in advence!

Comment: Forward declaration can only be used, for pointers (or references) to said class (e.g. `MainMenu* mainMenu;`) Otherwise - the size of `Credit` class can't be calculated at the time of compilation.

Comment: What would be the size of `MainMenu` or `Credit` ? You have to use some pointer.

Comment: Homm ok, thanks, i will try with pointers

Comment: Why would the credits menu have its own main menu? (Can there ever be more than one?)

Comment: it's actually a menu system where i have a Menu* variable who points to the menu that we display. In a menu i create a menu for every buttons. but i should make only one mainmenu, only one credit but i tried and there is always a problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is know as [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). Long story short, two objects should **never** have another as its subobject.

Instead you have two options. One is to have one *point* to another

```
class Credit : public Menu
{
private:
    MainMenu* mainMenu;
};
```

Or, you could have a manager of sorts, where only the manager is aware of both objects, and let them interact through the manager

```
class Manager
{
private:
    Credit credit;
    MainMenu mainMenu;
};
```

For the technical reason why you can't have a member of a declared but not defined type is because it is a incomplete type, and you can't have an object of incomplete type.

Comment: Humm if i create a manager class, i need to import it in my credit.h class too and i have a header loop :( how can i resolve this?

Comment: ok it work when i set in pointers in public and declare it in main.cpp

Comment: As Algirdas Preidžius said `MainMenu* mainMenu = new MainMenu();` will not work if `MainMenu` is an incomplete type.